# How to link more than one at a time in Greasmonkey click on the page?

Tags: click, greasemonkey

I am use simple clicking code for Greasmonkey but thats click only button.

My Code

```
setTimeout(function() {
    var evt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
    evt.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
    var link = document.querySelector("span.delete");
    link.dispatchEvent(evt);
}, 0);
```

This code deletes only one event :(

Page Source

```
 <div class="o_down">
       <span class="delete">Delete</span><input type="hidden" value="50203831" /><div class="cb"></div>
        </div>

      <div class="o_down">
       <span class="delete">Delete</span><input type="hidden" value="50203836" /><div class="cb"></div>
        </div>

      <div class="o_down">
       <span class="delete">Delete</span><input type="hidden" value="50203838" /><div class="cb"></div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Per the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelector), the `document.querySelector` function

> Returns the **first element** within the document (using depth-first pre-order traversal of the document's nodes) that matches the specified group of selectors

(emphasis added).

Try using [document.querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll).